# php quote inside quotes mixup

Tags: php, quotes, conditional-statements, double-quotes

I am trying to use a conditional on my nav items to add a class of active to the appropriate nav link when the pagetitle is equal to that page. New to php and the quotes inside quotes always gets me. right now my () and {} get messed up so the conditional does not run and every class gets active added to it

code:

```
<ul class="nav-global">
  <li class="nav-items <?php if($pageTitle = 'home'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items <?php if($pageTitle = 'about'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>about">About</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items <?php if($pageTitle = 'services'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>process">Services</a></li>
  <li class="nav-items <?php if($pageTitle = 'contact'){echo 'active';}?>"><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Pretty straightforward thanks in advance for the help

Comment: `if($pageTitle = 'home')` Maybe you meant `if($pageTitle == 'home')` ??

Comment: Also consider using variables?? E.g. assign `$myclass` and `$myhref` at the top and then simplify to `<li class="nav-items <?=$myclass?>"><a href="<?=$myhref?>">Home</a></li>` maybe its easier to read that way!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is your if statement. In this code:

```
if($pageTitle = 'home')
```

You are setting `$pageTitle` to `'home'`, then checking if it is truthy, which non-empty strings always are.

You want to test the string for equality with the equality operand `==`, with something like this.

```
if($pageTitle == 'home')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assiging `$pageTitle`

Use `==` to test if a string equals something,

```
if($pageTitle == 'home'){echo 'active';}?
```